# How to add a "%" after map Numbers in typescript for a frontend react?

Tags: arrays, typescript, object

`investments.map((el: any) => Number((el.percentage * 100).toFixed(3))) || []`

Hey i have this type of map the return a numbers on raeact front end, and i want to add "%" after each number and its always failed to me and aint show it on the dom after i try to add "%" in the map().

some one have soultion to that problem?

I try this one = investments.map((el: any) => Number((el.percentage * 100).toFixed(3)) **+ "%"**) || []

thanks for the helper!

Comment: Could you provide a bit more context - how does the `render()` function look where you are trying to put the contents?

Answer (score 1):

```
function App() {
const investments = [{
    id: 3,
    percentage: 10
  }, {
    id: 5,
    percentage: 20
  }
];

  return (
    <div className="App">        
      {investments.map((el: any) => <p>{Number((el.percentage * 100).toFixed(3))} %</p> || [])}
    </div>
  );
}
```

this worked for me. you can change that paragraph tag with whatever suits you